# How to check a button is disabled using Cypress

Tags: automated-testing, cypress

```
<button _ngcontent-c21="" color="primary" mat-button="" class="mat-button 
mat-primary" ng-reflect-disabled="true" ng-reflect-color="primary" 
disabled=""><span class="mat-button-wrapper">
```

The above contains and element that can enable or disable the button depending on the user rights. I'm trying to create a test to verify whether the button is active/disabled depending on the logged in user.
I'm trying to use

```
"expect($input).not.to.be.disabled"
```

but I'm not sure how to get this to work with my 'get' element (see below)

```
"cy.get('button.mat-button.mat-primary').eq(8)"
```

Answer (score 46):

Well this was embarrassingly simple

```
cy.get('button.mat-button.mat-primary').eq(8).should('not.be.disabled')
cy.get('button.mat-button.mat-primary').eq(8).should('be.disabled')
```

and this will allow me to check if buttons are disabled or not.  Didn't even need to use the "expect" route.

Answer (score 11):

The Cypress documentation shows examples how you can use `should()` to verify elements are enabled/disabled: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Assert-the-checkbox-is-disabled

```
cy.get(':button').should('be.disabled')
```

Answer (score 5):

Your question mentioned both active and visible and they are separate as in:

- visible / not-visible
- active / not-active (disabled but visible)

These two different pieces of state should be considered as in:

```
cy.get('.mySelector').should('be.visible').click();
cy.get('.mySelector').should('be.disabled');
cy.get('.mySelector').should('not.be.disabled');
```

Comment: Considering the age of this question and the other answers, it would help if you were to add an explanation of why your answer is an improvement on the other answers to this question.

Answer (score 4):

I recently found this code working in my case where I wanted to check if the element was enabled for next actions:

```js
this.button().then(($btn) => {
  if ($btn.is("enabled")) {
    //do something
  } else {
    //do something else
  }
})

// in cypress terms
    cy.get(':button').then((x) => {
      if (x.is("enabled")) {
        //do something if enabled
      } else {
        //do something else
      }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that `x.is('enabled')` is correct? Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64917850/25507) and my own tests, it should be `!x.is(':disabled')`.

Comment: I found Sasha's answer to be the best one.  I was looking for how to check if an element is enabled in order to determine the next actions.  Make sure to include Josh's correction, though.  I needed to include Josh's correction in order to get it to work.